# Cost of accessing an object in Scala

Tags: performance, scala

A bit of context:

```
case class Finger(length: Int)
case class Arm(thumb: Finger)
case class Body(rightArm: Arm, leftArm: Arm)
case class Human(body: Body)

def processHumanFinger(human: Human) = println(human.body.rightArm.thumb.length)

def processFingerOnly(finger: Finger) = println(finger.length)

val john = Human(Body(Arm(Finger(1)), Arm(Finger(3))))
val johnFinger = john.body.rightArm.thumb.length
```

I was wondering what was the difference in memory and time costs between those two pieces of code :

#### Sample 1

```
(1 to 1000000).foreach(_ => processFingerOnly(johnFinger))
```

and

#### Sample 2

```
(1 to 1000000).foreach(_ => processHumanFinger(john))
```

My question is mainly about knowing if the cost of accessing the human object in depth a million times (sample 2) is more expensive (in time and/or memory) than accessing it in depth once when assigning the `val johnFinger` then passing only the `Finger` object to the function (sample 1). But I am interested in every differences that exists between these two pieces of code !

Comment: well, have you run the code?

Comment: @Harald, yes and the results are quite weird .. Most of the time I get that the Sample 1 is slower but sometimes it is faster than Sample 2. Since I can't explain I was looking for some deeper explanation of what lies behind those calls and reads.

Comment: "sometimes slower and sometimes faster" really means "about the same". 
The difference in cost is so minuscule, that your crude benchmark isn't able to detect it, it gets shadowed by random stuff like cpu temperature, flukes in IO speed,  or the OS kicking you off the core for a few ticks.

Comment: @Dima That's what I thought but if by any chance you could explain what exactly happens under the hood, I'd like to know :)

Comment: You can see what happens for yourself with `javap`

Comment: The Java virtual machine has implemented a lot of optimization to improve the performance. In your case it's probably some kind of method inlining (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/whitepaper-135217.html#method) that plays the biggest role. Also note that the vm counts how often certain code is executed and might optimize and 'recompile' it after a certain number of invocations. Combined with GC and other things happening in the background it is non-trivial to benchmark such code properly.

Comment: it's not trivial...

Answer (score 0):

Using the following code, you can do a check to see how long each sample took.

**Preparation**

```
case class Finger(length: Int)
case class Arm(thumb: Finger)
case class Body(rightArm: Arm, leftArm: Arm)
case class Human(body: Body)

def processHumanFinger(human: Human) = human.body.rightArm.thumb.length
def processFingerOnly(finger: Finger) = finger.length

val john = Human(Body(Arm(Finger(1)), Arm(Finger(3))))
val johnFinger = john.body.rightArm.thumb.length

def time[R](block: => R): R = {
    val t0 = System.nanoTime()
    val result = block    // call-by-name
    val t1 = System.nanoTime()
    println("Elapsed time: " + (t1 - t0) + "ns")
    result
}
```

#### Sample 1

```
time {(1 to 10000000).foreach(_ => processFingerOnly(johnFinger))}
```

#### Sample 2

```
time {(1 to 10000000).foreach(_ => processHumanFinger(john))}
```

Through this simple timer, we can see that accessing an object at 1-level is around twice as fast as accessing an object at 4-level.

However, this could be a naiive approach, so I'm more than happy to hear people's opinions and feel free to edit!